# Is it possible to run Minecraft on an Android?

Tags: applications, compatibility, java

I was thinking in using some tools to convert the JAR into an APK. But will my Nexus One have enough memory? And what about the controls?

Comment: Egad, please no.  I lose enough time and sleep to Minecraft as it is without having it on my phone :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Minecraft Pocket Edition is available in the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftpe) and [Amazon's Appstore](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00992CF6W). Engadget has a  [hands-on](http://www.engadget.com/2011/06/07/minecraft-pocket-edition-on-xperia-play-hands-on-video/) of the game, and "SonyEricssonDev" [has a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmhZkRBQbig) showing Minecraft being played on the Xperia Play.

Comment: The pocket editions seems to give the player unlimited resources as the first versions of Minecraft did.

Answer (score 12):

I know nothing about Minecraft but I can't see how it would be possible without rewriting big chunks of it.  Even if you can convert the JAR to an .apk, there are many Java classes that are not part of the Android API.  Furthermore, Android does not include AWT, Swing or Java 2D/3D, it has its own UI and graphics APIs, so the user interface would need to be rewritten.

Comment: Minecraft uses *lots* of native per-platform code, mostly for OpenGL, audio and input handling. They supply versions for Windows, Mac OS and Linux i386/x86_64 - barely there's a chance that you can run that on a MIPS/ARM device..

Answer (score 9):

Android cannot just "run" native Java applications. Android does not have a Java Virtual Machine. Android uses a Dalvik Virtual Machine, which is completely different.

While android applications are written in Java, it is a "subset" of actual Java. so even if you could run the jar files through a "converter", there is no guarantee the code is actually supported by Dalvik.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a JAR provided that is a midlet for mobile (j2ME)

There are some JVM available in the market. I used them a lot in the early days of my G1 for some "killer apps" (Opera Mini, QQ)